# mvvm confustion with the model and business layer connection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, layer

So I have been searching for a while and all my searches on the model portion are just confusing me.

I have been seeing many examples where the view model has a direct reference to the model and then sets the model's member variables. However isn't the model supposed to be a business object so that the business layer can do calculations with that data?

So...

1) Should I share the model between both UI and the Business layer so both are referencing the exact same objects (shouldn't each layer "hide" their contents from each other in which case this wouldnt be the best).

http://blog.trivadis.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-01-50/1856.distributed_5F00_domain.png

2) Or should the model be in the business layer. Then the UI makes calls from the view model using provided business interfaces to access model info? This way the model itself is hidden from the UI. Similar to option 1's image except there would be some interface accessing the models and services.

3) Or UI does have the model. BUT I can see many occasions where the business layer would need this information resulting in multiple models which look relatively the exact same are made. Imagine that the entire picture below resides in the UI. Then there is a business layer below the model which the model accesses.
http://rarcher.azurewebsites.net/Images/mvvm00.png

Answer (score 2):

The **View** never has direct access to the Model. The View is connected to the ViewModel via its DataContext.

The **ViewModel** has direct access to the Model and is able to recover values from the Model and set values into it as well as call methods so that actions occur. But the ViewModel does not have direct access to the View, there could 0, 1 or many View instances all looking at the same ViewModel and it would never know.

The **Model** does not know about the existence of the ViewModel or View. Therefore you could reuse the Model class in a different project without any dependency on WPF or even a user interface.

How you attach the Model to the ViewModel is up to you. You could pass a reference to the Model into the constructor of the ViewModel. Or provide a separate method or property that is called after the ViewModel is constructed.

For complete separation you would expose the same list of properties on the ViewModel as are present on the Model itself (or just the subset actually needed). The ViewModel can hook into the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface that should be exposed from the Model. As it sees changes it can pass the change onto any watching View via its own properties and its own implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: I understand all this. The problem I am having is who actually owns the model and is it directly referenced by both the UI and Business layer. To me its sounding like option 1 that i provided is correct. But is option 2 a viable option? Option 2 seems more flexible for large projects but I have seen no examples showing or talking option 2. Thanks.

Comment: Technically ViewModel isn't UI (which seems you are confusing in all your options). ViewModel is presentation layer (in n-layer terms), which only contains persentation logic but is UI agnostic (read: You can reuse a ViewModel in a console app, in Windows Store App, Silverlight or MVC5 WebApp).A Model per see isn't only in one layer. There are different type of models.Your "domain" models are in the Domain (aka Busines) Layer. Other models are DataTransferObjects (subset or composition of business data for Cross Boundary concerns) or ViewModels (which prepare the data to be consumed by a view)

Comment: And you get DAO (DataAccess Objects) which are models which represent persistence and belong to the infrastructure layer. It's like with services. You have domain services and application services. domain services handle your domain/business logic. application services are specific to the type of application and go to the application layer. i.e FrameNavigationService (Prism for WindowsStoreApps) is very specific to navigation and only works in Windows Store Apps. It can't be reused in MVC Web-Applications

Comment: I guess what I am getting at here is that with this approach you described, its just redundant code because most everything will be the same between the models. I do think the DTOs is the key here though. Can DTOs be used across any layer? If so this would allow the passing of data from the VM model to a Domain model to a DAO and would seem to get rid of the redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Phil Wright states in his answer, the Model should have no knowledge of the ViewModel or the View, so you are free to reuse your Models between different layers. In my experience, Models are generally simple POCOs with no dependencies on other layers.

Whether you reuse your Models between your layers is up to you. If you're using an ORM such as Entity Framework, your Models might be your entity classes. Your business layer might decide to use these entity classes, or you may want to abstract them or aggregate them or do something else with them. *At the end of the day what goes in your Models is driven by what you want to store in them and how you want to use them, and SO can't really provide guidance on that because the question is so open-ended.*

As far as WPF and MVVM are concerned, I like to think of the ViewModel as being an aggregator of sorts for one or more Models. You generally pass the Model(s) to the ViewModel somehow (through its constructor or whatever): the ViewModel then provides properties and commands that are used by the View (via binding) in order to read and/or change the state of the ViewModel. At some later point, the ViewModel may need to change the state of the Models that it was supplied with, to reflect the changes initiated by the View.

You may find that the Models needed by your business layer are slightly different to the Models used by your ViewModels, and unfortunately you can end-up writing a lot of very similar-looking Model code when this happens. In such cases, Model interfaces may help: there's nothing to say that the Models used by a ViewModel have to be concrete classes. So you could have a single "sort of complex" Model that has all the properties needed by both your ViewModels and your business layer, then expose that Model through two different interfaces (one for each layer) so that properties irrelevant to a particular layer are not visible to it (if that makes sense!).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 1) Im starting to think since every layer may need their own model which probably have the same data, it may be best to have a DTO which all models base their data around. the VM may use a different model than that of some other domain BUT they all can pick and choose which member variables they want to use from the DTO and how to verify the data. 2) It also sounds like the model that the VM is using can also be a domain model assuming the functionality is very similar.